# StringLiteralConvertible and failable init

Tags: swift

When you cannot initialize an object due to invalid input, you can use a "[failable init](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_339)".

```
init?(s:String) {
   if s.isEmpty {
       return nil
   }
   // now set up instance vars
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var x:Foo = ""
if x == nil { blah blah
```

But is you conform to the StringLiteralConvertible protocol and implement those 3 inits, you cannot have a failable init.

My question: how do you check for invalid input when you use StringLiteralConvertible?

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/b40710734f3fd0538c8a.git) of those 3 inits if you've never used StringLiteralConvertible.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. You want *failable* `StringLiteralConvertible` initializers? or just want to have another failable initializer simultaneously with non failable `StringLiteralConvertible` initializers?

Comment: How do you check for invalid input when you use StringLiteralConvertible? You can't use a failable init. There is no try/catch in Swift. The only way I see is to validate the input before creating an instance. I'm asking if there is another way. Doesn't seem to be

Answer (score 0):

If you use StringLiteralConvertible, you can assign a literal string to a variable:

```
var x: Foo = "test"
```

Any string you provide is good, as long as it is a valid string. If it's not a string:

```
var x: Foo = 1
```

or it's a malformed string:

```
var x: Foo = test"
```

it won't pass compilation, so a failable initializer would be useless.

But if by valid you mean depending on the content of the string, then you are right. A literal must be syntactically correct and of the expected type in order to be considered valid in the context where it is used, and I don't think there's a way to override that.

Comment: Yes, I mean the content of the string. Doesn't seem to be a way to validate inside an init. What I'm doing now is to validate the string before creating an instance (calling init)